# Can I reuse a W9?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company

I created a Single Member LLC to do my IT Consulting/Training through.  Each new contract that I join requires me to fill out a W9.  This last time, I looked through the document and realized there was nothing different between the new W9 I was filling out, and any older W9 I had filled out before.  AKA, there didn't seem to be *(that I could find)* a place on the W9 that identified the new Employer.

That said, if all my information is the same (EIN, Address, Names, etc.)... whats to keep me from simply sending the same signed/scanned copy of my W9 to each new Employer that requests one of me?

Comment: Why do you think you can't?

Comment: @Joe Mostly because every new company sends me a new blank W9, and doesn't just ask for a completed W9.  I'm new to the LLC and working-for-yourself thing, so really, I have no idea ;)

Comment: There is a field for your account # /reference with the receiver, but it is optional and you don't have to fill it

Answer (score 3):

I think that it is technically feasible to re-use them, but at minimum you should have a new dated copy for each client/requester.  I'm unsure about the actual legalities of the situation; likely, the IRS would prefer you not to, but I can't find an explicit regulation.

That's because the IRS may wish to see your copy - particularly if something ends up mis-entered, but for other reasons as well, such as verifying backup withholding or auditing your client/requester for compliance.  Being able to show them separately dated copies for each client/requester makes it easier to prove you sent them a copy.

Also, it may throw your client off if you send them a copy that is dated months ago.

What I would recommend doing is having one copy saved without a signature and date, and then simply produce a new one to sign/date each time a client requests it.  That way you have your bases covered.

Comment: If one of our tax specialists knows a better answer to the first sentence, and would rather update my answer than make his/her own, please feel free to make the edit.  I couldn't find anything saying one way or the other in a quick search.

Comment: "reuse" is kindof meaningless here. Each receiver will have their own copy, its not that you can say "hey, yesterday I sent it to that guy, go look at his file if you want". So essentially, the OP is just asking whether he fill it once and photocopy each time (or scan/fax/whatever) and the answer is - of course.

Comment: Well, from what I have read in theory you should keep a copy of what was submitted - is that not true?

Comment: No, the receiver should keep  a copy